# Nginx is redirecting to www even though I didn't tell it to

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a node app that is running on port 8989 and it is being port-proxied to 80.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8989/;
    }
}
```

That works beautifully. But for some reason, the web address automatically goes to www when I type http://example.com into the browser bar. I didn't tell it to do that! haha

I checked the domain settings in my registrar to make sure I didn't stupidly set a www redirect over there. Nothing.

Finally, I looked at the console logs of requests to http://example.com and the response is a `302 moved temporarily`. Not sure how that happened, or why.

Where else can I look?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the server name for permanent

```
server {
     server_name  www.domain.com;
     rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name  domain.com;
    #The rest of your configuration goes here#
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your `8989` service is issuing the `302 redirect`, which is then being relayed by *nginx*. You should be looking at your `8989` service configuration to determine why it thinks it lives at `www.example.com`.